# Connect to DynamoDB from Angular 2 code

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have been trying all day to get access to dynamoDB from my code.

I have set up an IAM user with policy "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess", I have written down the access key id and secret access id.

I tried to put my credentials in a JSON, read it in code. Didn't work

I have tried use Environment variable, but it still console output, didn't find credentials, even I put it the location where AWS suggested.

Can someone show me a full example, with Angular 2, with Access key ID, Secret access key， from code, connect to dynamoDB, and list the tables there.

Thanks. All the answer I find online didn't work for me.

Comment: Storing access key and secret key in angular2 is not recommended, instead use AWS Cognito or STS to generate temporary security credentials.

Comment: If you code is running on an EC2 instance, use an IAM Role. The AWS SDK will automatically find credentials from a role. The search order for credentials is Environment, Profile, then Role. Do not store credentials on your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Using Amazon Cognito Identity to authenticate users and supply credentials
> 2. Using web federated identity
> 3. Hard coded in the script
>
> Warning
>
> We do not recommend hard coding your AWS credentials in your scripts.
>   Hard coding credentials poses a risk of exposing your access key ID
>   and secret access key.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html

[Web Federated Identity Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/config-web-identity-examples.html)